# PyMongo create_index only if it does not exist

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

In a Python script using PyMongo, an index is created for a collection using the line

```
myCollection.create_index('Datetime', unique=True)
```

However this throws an error the next time the script is executed because the index already exist.

**Question:** Is there a way to check for the existance of an index before deciding whether to call `create_index`?

Answer (score 22):

In PyMongo 3.6.0 and later, calling `create_index` will not recreate the index if it already exists and will not throw an error. The index creation will just be ignored if the index already exists.

Comment: Are you able to cite any sources that document this behavior?

Comment: Second bullet point on the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#behaviors)

Comment: _Who can deal with these unrealistic scientific standards of evidence?_ :) Thanks @GabrielFair, the default behavior works as detailed.

Comment: This works only for indexes that are not unique. If you already have an index that is unique, you'll get pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError, when calling create_index again.

Comment: My pymongo version is 3.11.3 and mongodb version is 4.4.3, but it gives `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Index with name: {INDEX_NAME} already exists with a different name` if an index with the same field exists. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: I confirmed this in 3.9, using the same statement twice in a row: `    db.my_coll.create_index('name', unique=True)`. It caused no problems.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`index_information()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information) method:

> Get information on this collection’s indexes.
>
> Returns a dictionary where the keys are index names (as returned by
>   create_index()) and the values are dictionaries containing information
>   about each index.

```
index_name = 'Datetime'
if index_name not in myCollection.index_information():
    myCollection.create_index(index_name, unique=True)
```

There is also [`list_indexes()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes) method which can also be used to solve it, but the output format is not that convenient as in case of `index_information()`.

And, there is that [`ensure_index()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.ensure_index) method, that looks exactly what you are asking about, but this method is now deprecated.

Comment: The keys of the dict returned by index_information() are index names (as returned by create_index), which are different from the index keys. Are you sure your code works ?
Note that it is possible to specify a custom name when creating an index.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
def ensure_index(conn, index):
    """
    Creates the index if it does not exist.
    Input Args:
        conn: MongoClient object, created using uri.
        index: List of index tuples. Example:
            [('age', pymongo.DESCENDING), ('sex', pymongo.ASCENDING)]
    """
    index = index or []
    index_str = '_'.join(
        map(lambda x: '%s_%s' %(x[0], x[1]), index)
    )

    indexes = conn.index_information().keys()
    if index_str and index_str not in indexes:
        conn.create_index(index, background=True)
```